# How to append value dynamic div jquery

Tags: jquery

I add a div after set a value this div but not set

my code:

```
$('body').append("<div id=\"114\"></div>"); // its work
$('#114').html("text");   //not work
$('#114').text("text");   //not work
$('#114').append("text");  //not work
```

Comment: @Andy in HTML5 that's ok

Comment: They can start with a number, but you have to use different selector notation.

Comment: your quotes here `"<div id="114"></div>"` need to be escaped - or use single quotes on the outside

Comment: Can you make a jsFiddle that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: So, what is not working now that you have edited your post with escaping quotes?

Comment: It's for this reason that I use single quotes for JS and double for HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Escape quotes in string:

```
$('body').append("<div id=\"114\"></div>"); // its work
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DdbMb/

Comment: ı use escape quetes forget write now. ı see in browser source code my div but not change value

Comment: so your code works... Otherwise provide a jsfiddle to replicate your issue